# NGNIX Redirect with two Parameter

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect, redirection

So at the moment this is working for me:

```
if ($request_uri = "/web/news.php?id=69") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/? last;
}
```

But now I also have URLs like `/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020` with two Parameters instead of one like above.

```
if ($request_uri = "/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020? last;
}
```

this doesn't seem to work. Do you have any suggestions?

Since it redirected me to the site with german parameters, I redirected them and it worked like this for me in the end:

```
if ($request_uri = "/news/aktuell.html?monat=02&jahr=2020") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020? last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($args ~* "/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=$arg_monat&year=$arg_jahr? last;
}
```

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Just adapt to your needs.

Comment: it somehow redirects me to https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?monat=02&jahr=2020 instead of month and year..

Comment: @ac_s_fer The `$args` variable value can be either `monat=02&jahr=2020` or `jahr=2020&monat=02` but not the `/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020`, your solution is close to the working one but would not work because of reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach. Add a `map` into `http` level:

```
map $arg_id $idmap {
    default 0;
    "69" 1;
}

map $arg_monat $monatmap {
    default 0;
    "02" 1;
}

map $arg_jahr $jahrmap {
    default 0;
    "2020" 1;
```

Then use following `if` blocks:

```
if ($idmap = 1) {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/? last;
}

if ($jahrmap$monatmap = "11") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020 last;
}
```

`map` maps contents of input variable to output variable. `$arg_id` takes query argument `id` from URI. In the `map` above, nginx compares the `id` argument to `69`. If it matches, `$idmap` gets value 1. Otherwise it gets value 0.

Arguments `monat` and `jahr` are handled similarly. Their output variables are concatenaed in `if` comparison, and if both arguments match values specified in `map`, then the `rewrite` is performed.

Comment: I made an http{} containing the maps. That kills all links on my Site.
I dont have/see an already available http-level. How can I access it without breaking everything?

Comment: The `http` level usually exists in `nginx.conf` file. Depending on your distribution, you can add the `map` blocks to a file that is included in `http` level.